# Connectivity between VM on KVM using hostdev forwarding mode

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, linux-kvm, ubuntu-18.04

I have a problem with KVM. I have an Agilio Netronome SmartNIC which is compatible with the SR-IOV technology (like my OS - ubuntu 18.04 - and BIOS).

I have configured a Network with virsh for managing the selection of the VF :

```
<network>
   <name>passthrough</name> <!-- This is the name of the file you created -->
   <forward mode='hostdev' managed='yes'>
      <pf dev='enp2s0np0'/>
   </forward>
</network>
```

And I have declared interfaces for my VM :

```
   <interface type='hostdev' managed='yes'>
     <source network='passthrough'>
        <address type='pci' domain='0' bus='2' slot='8' function='1'/>
     </source>
     <mac address='52:54:00:6d:90:01'/>
   </interface>
```

The interface is on the VM, with the good driver, etc. but it can't join the host machine or the other VM.

Anyone know how to have connectivity when using the hostdev forwarding mode ?